# Console password for SRX 650 juniper router

Tags: juniper-srx

How do I set the password for the console port on a Juniper SRX650 router?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default the only username configured is root. Thus setting password is a matter of using:

```
`set system root-authentication plain-text-password`
```

- This is auto-encrypted once entered in.

It is best practice not to be logging in as root however unless special circumstances requires it... even then you would log in as a normal user and 'su root' to gain elevated privileges.

What I would do is setup a user profile under 'set system login':

```
user testuser {
       full-name "Your USER FULLNAME";
       uid 2004;
       class super-user;
       authentication {
            encrypted-password "password";
      }
}
```

Once committed this will allow you to use the configured user as a local login.

The authentication order will need to be changed if you want to use 'radius/tacacs + local password authentication as backup'